# Turn environment variable into an array

Tags: powershell

I need to pass an array to a PowerShell subprocess and was wondering how I can turn an environment variable (string) into a PowerShell array. Is there a convention I need to follow so PowerShell will do it for me automatically or I just need to parse it myself?

I'm looking for something similar to what `bash` can do. If I set an environment variable such as:

```
MYARR = one two three
```

It'll be automatically interpreted by `bash` as an array, so I can do:

```
for a in ${MYARR[@]} ; do
    echo Element: $a
done
```

And that will return:

```
Element: one
Element: two
Element: three
```

Is there a way I can do the same in PowerShell?

Comment: you can use the -split option on the string and specify a delimiter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Split the value of the environment variable at whatever delimiter is used. Example:

```
PS C:\> $env:Path
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
PS C:\> $a = $env:Path -split ';'
PS C:\> $a
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
PS C:\> $a.GetType().FullName
System.String[]
```

---

**Edit:** The PowerShell equivalent to `bash` code like this

```
for a in ${MYARR[@]} ; do
    echo Element: $a
done
```

would be

```
$MYARR -split '\s+' | ForEach-Object {
    "Element: $_"
}
```

Use `$env:MYARR` instead of `$MYARR` if the variable is an actual environment variable instead of a PowerShell variable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it would need that I change the calling script and add the split command on the top. I wasn't precise in my original question, so please have a look at my edit.

Comment: @Jacek I fail to see why you think you'd need to put the split in the calling script.

Comment: :-) right the trouble with your edit is that it doesn't look as appealing as the original PS arrays: `foreach ($element in $MYARR) {$element}`

Comment: @Jacek That would have to be `foreach ($element in ($MYARR -split '\s+')) { $element }`, and I prefer working with pipelines.